# How to validate multiple images input?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this function which will allow users to upload one image or more. I already create the validation rules but it keep returning false no matter what the input is.

Rules :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp',
        ];
    }
```

Upload method :

```
public function addIM(PhotosReq $request) {
        $id = $request->id;
        // Upload Image
        foreach ($request->file('image') as $file) {
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_name = str_random(8) . ".$ext";
            $upload_path = 'image';
            $file->move($upload_path, $image_name);
            Photos::create([
                'post_id' => $id,
                'image' => $image_name,
            ]);
        }
        //Toastr notifiacation
        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Images added successfully!',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );
        return back()->with($notification);
    }
```

How to solve this ? 
That's all and thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple image upload field name like and add `multiple` attribute to your input element

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple">
```

So that, your input is like array inside which there will be images. 
Since there is different method for array input validation, see docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays).

So, you have to validate something like this:

```
$this->validate($request,[
     'image' => 'required',
     'image.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp',
]);
```

Hope,You understand

Comment: Congrats bro, Feels good it helped you.
So, please close question